# Python 3.5 typing custom type

Tags: python-3.x, typechecking, mypy

I have a method that calls an API and that API responds with a dict which contains two keys: `all`, `owner` (it's a Github api actually that gets the commit activity for a given repository)

I'm playing with the newly integrated `typing` module/system into Python 3.5 and I want to know if it's possible to create a custom type that actually specifies that the `Dict` returned should contain these two keys (`all` and `owner`)

Here's what I have so far:

`TypeRepositoryCommitActivity = Dict[str, List]`

These are obviously primitive types assembled together so how do I go enforcing a little deeper?

Answer (score 1):

Until this becomes available in `typing`, you can use mypy extended features:

```
from mypy_extensions import TypedDict

TypeRepoCommits = TypedDict('TypeRepoCommits', {'all': str, 'owner': str})

x: TypeRepoCommits = {'all': 'a', 'owner': 'b'} # pass type check
y: TypeRepoCommits = {'all': 1, 'owner': 'b'} # fail type check
```